# How to fix AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

My output:

[image: img]

```
def load_data(self):
    """
    Load data from list of paths
    :return: 3D-array X and 2D-array y
    """
    X = None
    y = None
    df = pd.read_excel('data/Data.xlsx', header=None)
    for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        sentences_ = df[i].to_numpy().tolist()
        label_vec = [0.0 for _ in range(0, self.n_class)]
        label_vec[i] = 1.0
        labels_ = [label_vec for _ in range(0, len(sentences_))]
        if X is None:
            X = sentences_
            y = labels_
        else:
            X += sentences_
            y += labels_
    X, max_length = self.tokenize_sentences(X)
    X = self.word_embed_sentences(X, max_length=self.max_length)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

This is my code with pandas library as pd. When I run in Google Colab I get the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

Comment: Please add the error output for more details, like at which line does the error occurs ?

Comment: What pandas version are you using? You could try `df[i].values.tolist()` ?

Comment: Eror in sentences_ = df[i].to_numpy().tolist()

Comment: I use pandas 0.24.1

Comment: `to_numpy()` is a new method, I'd double check your Pandas version in the colab - maybe it doesn't match

Comment: Oh Yeah. I will update pandas version  from 0.22.0 to 0.24.1 in Google Colab and It run for me. Thank you every one

Answer (score 27):

Check the version of your pandas library:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

If your version is less than 0.24.1:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 19):

If you need your code to work with all versions of pandas, here's a simple way to convert a Series into a NumPy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1.1, 2.3])
a = np.array(s)
print(a)  # [1.1 2.3]
```

---

On an advanced note, if your Series has missing values (as NaN values), these can be converted to a masked array:

```
s = pd.Series([1.1, np.nan])
a = np.ma.masked_invalid(s)
print(a)  # [1.1 --]
```